# Redemption issue with GetMessageFromMsgFile and Attachment Enumeration

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am having issues iterating through the Attachments collection of an **RDOMail** object. If I open an external MSG file using **GetMessageFromMsgFile** and attempt to iterate through the attachments a second time I receive an **E_ACCESSDENIED** exception. I have tried accessing the attachments using For Each, GetEnumerator and the Item property. In all of these scenarios, the first time I access an attachment it works, but any subsequent attempts fail with the Access Denied error.

> ************** Exception Text **************
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from  HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at  System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext()

I have tried the same code on the same message but opened directly from the Inbox, and it works as expected and I can iterate the attachments multiple times.

The issue seems related to VB.NET assemblies, as I can iterate the Attachments of an external MSG file multiple times if I use the same code in VBA in Excel for example.

The trouble is, I need to process lots of external MSG files on the file system, with the ability to interrogate the attachments a number of times from a VB.NET assembly.

I am in the process of evaluating Redemption, before purchasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the messages created on top of MSG files won't let you access attachments or attachment table objects again until the first instance of the corresponding object is released.

Make sure you avoid using multiple dot notation (to avoid implicit variables) and release all Redemption objects as soon as you are done with them using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`. You might also want to call `GC.Collect()` after processing the file to release all pending objects in case there are still hanging references.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I'm  not sure I understand? It works as expected in VBA. How do you mean messages created on top of MSG files? I am simply opening a MSG file to create an instance of an RDOMail. Could you please clarify.

Comment: Hi Dmity, don't worry. As you say ReleaseComObject on the Attachment object makes it work as expected.

Comment: Another quick question if I may. What is the recommended way to resolve an Exchange EX address to an SMTP address in Redemption. MAPIUtils states it is obsolete. Thanks

Comment: If you already have the corresponding GAL RDOAddressEntry object, you can just use RDOAddressEntry.SMTPAddress. Otherwise you can use RDOSession.Addressbook.ExchangeAddressToEntryId / RDOSession.GetAddressEntryFromID / RDOAddressEntry.SMTPAddress

Comment: Thanks, that’s great. I will give that a try.